# Does the OpenSearch query syntax support boolean operations on document fragments?

Tags: amazon-opensearch

Imagine an OpenSearch index with the following 2 documents.

```
POST /test/_doc
{
  "name": "name",
  "array": [
    {
      "foo": "bar",
      "cat": "meow"
    },
    {
      "foo": "bar",
      "cat": "woof"
    },
    {
      "foo": "apple",
      "cat": "meow"
    }
  ]
}

POST /test/_doc
{
  "name": "name",
  "array": [
    {
      "foo": "bar",
      "cat": "woof"
    },
    {
      "foo": "apple",
      "cat": "meow"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a boolean query that looks at the properties `array.foo` and `array.cat`.

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {"array.foo": "bar"}},
        {"match": {"array.cat": "meow"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This query returns both sample documents.

Is there a way to scope the search to look for documents containing an array element that has both of these values?  In this instance, only the first document would be returned.